# RSA fixed point

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

What is the number of RSA fixed points, in other words how many $m$ are there such that
$$m^e\equiv m \pmod{n}$$
where $n=pq$, for primes $p,q$.

I know that the answer is $(1+\text{gcd}(e^n-1,p-1))\cdot (1+\text{gcd}(e^n-1,q-1))$, but I could use some help on proving it.

Comment: I think it's $(1+\gcd(e-1,p-1))(1+\gcd(e-1,q-1))$. Do you have a citation that shows otherwise?

Comment: @user3491648 Yours seems OK, see [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397509006902).

Comment: OP's versions seems to be for a slightly different version, see [link](https://books.google.de/books?id=5cIN7kemQgYC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=rsa+fixed+point&source=bl&ots=GLhfTOQvdX&sig=Y1G-IzmBff3WaQUQTqjmqIXb1qg&hl=de&sa=X&ei=Z5JjVdyLD8H4Uv3HgLgM&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw) at the bottom.

Comment: @mvw Makes sense, thanks. If that's the case, it should be $m^{e^n}≡m \pmod N$, and $N=pq$ (capital N). The method in that case would be the same as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using CRT, $$m^e \equiv m \pmod p \\ m^e \equiv m \pmod q$$

Mod p: Either $$m \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$ or $$e \log m \equiv \log m \pmod{p-1} \iff \\ (e - 1) \log m \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$$
Now count the number of values of $\log m$. $\log m$ is any multiple of $\frac{p-1}{\gcd(e-1,p-1)}$. The number of multiples is $\gcd(e-1,p-1)$.

Same story mod q.

So it's $(1+\gcd(e-1,p-1))(1+\gcd(e-1,q-1))$.

[edit]

Included $m = 0$ case.