# bob sends a message to amazon x=102, how should he encrypt his message using the public key and what is the result?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

Please help me with this question related to RSA.
$p=13$, $q=19$
$x=(p-1)(q-1)=216$
$N=p*q=247$
So three values of $e$ were given in the question $37,38,39$ using the fact $\gcd(x,e)$ , I found the value of $e=37$.
 So $e=37$ 
 and I calculated $d$ which is equal to $181$.
Is the value of $d$ correct?
Then when I started encoding the message using 102(power 37)mod(247), I got the result = $102$.

How is this even possible?
Please tell me my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed among the three numbers, only $37$ has $\gcd(37, \phi(N)) = 1$, where $\phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1)$.
Indeed $181 \cdot 37 = 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$, so your $d$ is correct.

No mistake, indeed $102^{37} = 102 \pmod{N}$ and also $102^{181} = 102 \pmod{N}$ (so "decryption" also works).

You just happen to have a fixed point for RSA. There are always

$(1+\gcd(e-1,p-1))(1+\gcd(e-1,q-1))$ of them,see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1298698/4280). $1$ is always one. In this case $p-1 | e$ and $q-1 | e$ so all points are fixed points. This never happens in praxis, as then $p,q$ are chosen so that $p-1$ only has one prime factor, besides 2, and likewise for $q-1$. And $e=2^{16}+1$ or $e=3$ is chosen, so that $\gcd(e-1, p-1) = 2 = \gcd(e-1, q-1)$, and there are very few (9, among which $0,1$) fixed points. Plus messages are padded to look random, os the fixed points will rarely be hit. But it's a weird example to use; only for such small numbers we can make an "identity" RSA. But it's very atypical.

Comment: Actually I have to decrypt an encrypted message y=141 using d=181 and so i am getting the result 141.

Comment: So this is not wrong , right?

Comment: @bardaamir yes 141 decrypts to 141. Another fixed point.

Comment: $p-1 = 12$ an $q-1 = 18$ have lots of common divisors with $e-1 = 36$. So there are $19 \cdot 13$ fixed points, i.e. all of them. This RSA trivialises: always crypto = plain.